# Dont work pagination using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework.I am doing a select data  form database and list it with pagination.my controller is Sitecontroller.php,view file is search_result.php

Controller-Sitecontroller.php

```
 <?php
 class SiteController extends Controller
 {
 public function actionsearch_result()
  {
    $title=$_GET['title'];
    $experience=$_GET['experience'];
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
    $count=Job::model()->count($criteria);
    $pages=new CPagination($count);
    $pages->pageSize=2;
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
  $model=Job::model()->findAll(array('select'=>'*',
 "condition"=>"(title like     '%$title%')  
 or (key_skills like '%$title%')",));
  $this->render('search_result',array('model' =>$model,'title' =>$title,
  'experience'   =>$experience,'pages' => $pages));

  }
```

}
   ?>

View-search_result.php

```
   <div style="float:right;margin-right:285px;">
   <h1>Search Results</h1>
   <ul style="list-style:none; ">
   <?php

foreach($model as $models)  
   { 
 $job_id=$models->id;
 ?>
  <li><p><?php echo $models->title; ?></p>

  <p><?php echo $models->company_name; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $models->description; ?></p>
  <p>Keyskill:<?php echo $models->key_skills; ?><p>

  </li>
  <?php
   }
  ?>
</ul>    
  <p><?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
     'pages' => $pages,
   )) ?></p>
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) like [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/post.display#customizing-x-10x-operation), and i strongly recommend to read [The Definitive Guide to Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/) and [The Yii Blog Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/).